# Python multiple if statements for petrol price movement

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

**Situation:**
I buy a certain volume of petrol at price X, which is usually sold within a 30 days. During these 30 days, I will need to adjust my petrol station gas price according to average State gas price. If State price goes up by 1.2% from my purchased price, I will set my price to +1% of my purchased price.

Here is an example:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-wa1i{font-weight:bold;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle}
.tg .tg-7zrl{text-align:left;vertical-align:bottom}
.tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-wa1i">Time</th>
    <th class="tg-wa1i">Average state&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;gas price</th>
    <th class="tg-wa1i">Av state price&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;change, %</th>
    <th class="tg-wa1i">My price change,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;%</th>
    <th class="tg-wa1i">My station gas&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;price</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                         4.231 </td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"> - </td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">  - </td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">           4.231 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                         4.337 </td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                   2.5%</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                     2.0%</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">           4.316 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                         4.437 </td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                   4.9%</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                     4.0%</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">           4.400 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">4</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                         4.481 </td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                   5.9%</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                     5.0%</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">           4.443 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">5</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                         4.571 </td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                   8.0%</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                     8.0%</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">           4.569 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">6</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                         4.616 </td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                   9.1%</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                     9.0%</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">           4.612 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">7</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                         4.709 </td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                 11.3%</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                  11.0%</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">           4.696 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-7zrl">8</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                         4.850 </td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                 14.6%</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">                  14.0%</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">           4.823 </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a python code but it is very clunky, and if gas price moves up by 20%, then I have to write my_priceX up to 20 times. Is there a more elegant solution?

```
my_price1 = last_gas_price["price"]*1.01 
my_price2 = last_gas_price["price"]*1.02 
my_price3 = last_gas_price["price"]*1.03 
my_price4 = last_gas_price["price"]*1.04  
my_price5 = last_gas_price["price"]*1.05 

if last_gas_price > my_price1:
    adj_price(price = my_price1)

if last_gas_price > my_price2:
    adj_price(price = my_price2)

if last_gas_price > my_price3:
    adj_price(price = my_price3)

if last_gas_price > my_price4:
    adj_price(price = my_price4)

if last_gas_price > my_price5:
    adj_price(price = my_price5)
```

Comment: Have you learned about using "for loops"?

Comment: State increase of 1.2% means you increase by 1%. Why? is there a set of values that you have to lookup? Or is your increase based on a formula against the state increase?

Comment: It is based on formula. I am ok to be up to 0.99% less expensive vs State average, but not more. and I would like to increase price in 1% fixed step increments.